# How does request::is_ajax() work in Kohana?

Tags: php, ajax, kohana

How does Kohana determine if a request is an AJAX one?

Is there anything different in the referrer string? Do I need to add a GET param, perhaps `?ajax=true` ?

Comment: Oh man, just look in to the source!

Comment: As a PHP noob, it wasn't that easy for me to track where it was in the source (at least when I asked the question).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It checks if the request is made by XMLHttpRequest since most browser send a header in this case with this indication: header `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` would be set to `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: It would appear from Jonathan Sampson's answer that it is not the browser, but the framework that is setting the header.

Comment: Well.. the header is send by the browser when the request is made. The framework would not know if the request was made via XMLHttpRequest or a normal http GET if the client (browser) would not indicate it.

Answer (score 5):

As of v2.3.4

```
/**
 * Tests if the current request is an AJAX request by checking the 
 * X-Requested-With HTTP request header that most popular JS frameworks 
 * now set for AJAX calls.
 *
 * @return  boolean
 */

public static function is_ajax()
{
  return (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND 
          strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Necro-posting because this came up first my google search.

Dunno if Kohana still works this way, but using HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH is no longer best practice.

Ajax requests -- all HTTP requests actually -- should send an "Accept" header.

Any server-side process should examine the "Accept" header to determine what content to send in response. One way to do this in PHP is:

```
  function is_ajax() {
    return $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] == 'application/json';
  }
```